# Cassandra bootstrap hang in join state for a very long time

Tags: cassandra

Our production environment has two cassandra node(v2.0.5), and we want to add additional node to extend scalability. We followed step desc in [Datastax doc](https://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_add_node_to_cluster_t.html)

After bootstrap new node, we observed some exception log
`ERROR [CompactionExecutor:42] 2015-03-25 19:01:01,821 CassandraDaemon.java (line 192) Exception in thread Thread[CompactionExecutor:42,1,main]
    java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.TombstoneOverwhelmingException
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.pager.QueryPagers$1.next(QueryPagers.java:154)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.pager.QueryPagers$1.next(QueryPagers.java:137)`

And it repeat some compaction task and after two week it didn't complete bootstrap. Node remains not join state

`INFO [CompactionExecutor:4468] 2015-03-30 09:18:20,288 ColumnFamilyStore.java (line 784) Enqueuing flush of Memtable-compactions_in_progress@1247174540(212/13568 serialized/live bytes, 7 ops)
 INFO [FlushWriter:314] 2015-03-30 09:18:22,408 Memtable.java (line 373) Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/production_alarm_keyspace/alarm_history_data_new/production_alarm_keyspace-alarm_history_data_new-jb-118-Data.db (11216962 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1427280544702, position=24550137)
     INFO [FlushWriter:314] 2015-03-30 09:18:22,409 Memtable.java (line 333) Writing Memtable-alarm_master_data@37361826(26718076/141982437 serialized/live bytes, 791595 ops)
     INFO [FlushWriter:314] 2015-03-30 09:18:24,018 Memtable.java (line 373) Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/production_alarm_keyspace/alarm_master_data/production_alarm_keyspace-alarm_master_data-jb-346-Data.db (8407637 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1427280544702, position=24550137)
     INFO [FlushWriter:314] 2015-03-30 09:18:24,018 Memtable.java (line 333) Writing Memtable-compactions_in_progress@1247174540(212/13568 serialized/live bytes, 7 ops)
     INFO [FlushWriter:314] 2015-03-30 09:18:24,185 Memtable.java (line 373) Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/compactions_in_progress/system-compactions_in_progress-jb-1019-Data.db (201 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1427280544702, position=24550511)
     INFO [CompactionExecutor:4468] 2015-03-30 09:18:24,186 CompactionTask.java (line 115) Compacting [SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/production_alarm_keyspace/alarm_common_dump_by_minutes/production_alarm_keyspace-alarm_common_dump_by_minutes-jb-356-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/production_alarm_keyspace/alarm_common_dump_by_minutes/production_alarm_keyspace-alarm_common_dump_by_minutes-jb-357-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/production_alarm_keyspace/alarm_common_dump_by_minutes/production_alarm_keyspace-alarm_common_dump_by_minutes-jb-355-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/production_alarm_keyspace/alarm_common_dump_by_minutes/production_alarm_keyspace-alarm_common_dump_by_minutes-jb-354-Data.db')]
     INFO [CompactionExecutor:4468] 2015-03-30 09:18:39,189 ColumnFamilyStore.java (line 784) Enqueuing flush of Memtable-compactions_in_progress@810255650(0/0 serialized/live bytes, 1 ops)
 INFO [FlushWriter:314] 2015-03-30 09:18:39,189 Memtable.java (line 333) Writing Memtable-compactions_in_progress@810255650(0/0 serialized/live bytes, 1 ops)
     INFO [FlushWriter:314] 2015-03-30 09:18:39,357 Memtable.java (line 373) Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/compactions_in_progress/system-compactions_in_progress-jb-1020-Data.db (42 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1427280544702, position=25306969)
     INFO [CompactionExecutor:4468] 2015-03-30 09:18:39,367 CompactionTask.java (line 275) Compacted 4 sstables to [/var/lib/cassandra/data/production_alarm_keyspace/alarm_common_dump_by_minutes/production_alarm_keyspace-alarm_common_dump_by_minutes-jb-358,].  70,333,241 bytes to 70,337,669 (~100% of original) in 15,180ms = 4.418922MB/s.  260 total partitions merged to 248.  Partition merge counts were {1:236, 2:12, }`

Nodetool status just show two node, and it's accept because 2.0.5 has bug in nodetool don't show join node.
`[bpmesb@bpmesbap2 ~]$ nodetool status
     Datacenter: datacenter1
     =======================
     Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
    --  Address      Load       Tokens  Owns   Host ID                               Rack
     UN  172.18.8.56  99 GB      256     51.1%  7321548a-3998-4122-965f-0366dd0cc47e  rack1
    UN  172.18.8.57  93.78 GB   256     48.9%  bb306032-ff1c-4209-8300-d8c3de843f26  rack1`

Can anybody help about this condition? Because datastax says bootstrap only take few minutes but our situation didn't complete after 2 weeks? We search stackoverflow and find [This issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25019741/cassandra-hangs-on-arbitrary-commands)

may be related to our problem

Answer (score 0):

After few days test and look at exception log. We found this may be key issue about this problem.

```
ERROR 19:01:01,821 Exception in thread Thread[NonPeriodicTasks:1,5,main]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.TombstoneOverwhelmingException
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.waitOnFuture(FBUtilities.java:413)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.index.SecondaryIndexManager.maybeBuildSecondaryIndexes(SecondaryIndexManager.java:140)
at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamReceiveTask$OnCompletionRunnable.run(StreamReceiveTask.java:113)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
```

The log shows that one stream receiver task encounter tombstone overwhelming exception. And we think that's the key point cause cassandra never change state to normal.

And here is following step we done to fix this problem. We use nodetool to compact table and secondary index at two original node.

```
nohup nodetool compact production_alarm_keyspace object_daily_data &
nohup nodetool rebuild_index production_alarm_keyspace object_daily_data object_daily_data_alarm_no_idx_1 &
```

And we restart new node again, and after a hour, new node jump to normal and work fine until now.